# Were Shimon and Levi allowed to do what they did?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, murder, vayishlach

Shimon and Levi deceive and kill out an entire city, yet Yaakov only curses their hasty anger, not their actions. Were they allowed to do what they did?

Comment: Allowed by whom?  Yaakov, or are you asking about divine sanction?

Answer (score 7):

The Ramban on the story quotes the Rambam as saying that the inhabitants of Shechem were required to judge (the person) Shechem and did not. As such, they did not fulfill the obligation of the descendants of Noach to judge justly. A descendant of Noach that fails to fulfill one if his 7 obligations (namely 1. belief in the creator, 2. prohibition of incest, 3. prohibition of theft, 4. prohibition of murder 5. prohibition of eating livre animals, 6. prohibition of idolatry, 7. to judge justly) he is to be executed. The inhabitants of Shechem did't do #7 so were put to death. The Ramban debates this explanation for the city of Shechem, but that is at least what the Rambam says.

Comment: ורבים ישאלו, ואיך עשו בני יעקב הצדיקים המעשה הזה לשפוך דם נקי. והרב השיב בספר שופטים (רמב"ם הלכות מלכים פ"ט הי"ד) ואמר שבני נח מצווים על הדינים, והוא להושיב דיינין בכל פלך ופלך לדון בשש מצות שלהן, ובן נח שעבר על אחת מהן הוא נהרג בסייף, ראה אחד שעבר על אחת מהן ולא דנוהו להרגו הרי זה הרואה יהרג בסייף. ומפני זה נתחייבו כל בעלי שכם הריגה שהרי שכם גזל, והם ראו וידעו ולא דנוהו:
  ואין דברים הללו נכונים בעיני, שאם כן היה יעקב אבינו חייב להיות קודם וזוכה במיתתם, ואם פחד מהם למה כעס על בניו וארר אפם אחר כמה זמנים, וענש אותם וחלקם והפיצם, והלא הם זכו ועשו מצוה ובטחו באלהים והצילם:

Comment: ועל דעתי הדינין שמנו לבני נח בשבע מצות שלהם אינם להושיב דיינין בכל פלך ופלך בלבד, אבל צוה אותם בדיני גנבה ואונאה ועושק ושכר שכיר ודיני השומרים ואונס ומפתה ואבות נזיקין וחובל בחבירו ודיני מלוה ולוה ודיני מקח וממכר וכיוצא בהן, כענין הדינין שנצטוו ישראל, ונהרג עליהן אם גנב ועשק או אנס ופתה בתו של חבירו או שהדליק גדישו וחבל בו וכיוצא בהן. ומכלל המצוה הזאת שיושיבו דיינין גם בכל עיר ועיר כישראל, ואם לא עשו כן אינן נהרגין, שזו מצות עשה בהם, ולא אמרו (סנהדרין נז א) אלא אזהרה שלהן זו היא מיתתן, ולא תיקרא אזהרה אלא המניעה בלאו, וכן דרך הגמרא בסנהדרין (נט ב):

Comment: the above was the Rambam. This is the Ramban:

Comment: אבל ענין שכם, כי בני יעקב, בעבור שהיו אנשי שכם רשעים ודמם חשוב להם כמים רצו להנקם מהם בחרב נוקמת, והרגו המלך וכל אנשי עירו כי עבדיו הם, וסרים אל משמעתו, ואין הברית אשר נמולו נחשב בעיניהם למאומה כי היה להחניף לאדוניהם, ויעקב אמר להם בכאן כי הביאוהו בסכנה שנאמר עכרתם אותי להבאישני, ושם ארר אפם כי עשו חמס לאנשי העיר, שאמרו להם במעמדו וישבנו אתכם והיינו לעם אחד, והם היו בוחרים בהם ובעטו בדבורם, ואולי ישובו אל ה' והרגו אותם חנם, כי לא הרעו להם כלל. וזהו שאמר כלי חמס מכרותיהם (להלן מט ה):

Comment: Could you incorporate the quotes into your answer?