# Shimon and Levi in Shechem

Tags: vayishlach, pictures

There is a picture illustrated by a seemingly Orthodox artist depicting Shimon and Levi with their swords drawn and the people of Shechem on their knees with their hands up. Although the shevatim's actions against the men of the city was justified [in multiple](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22516/13811) [posts before](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49100/13811), are there any Torah sources which 'paint' a similar picture? (I assumed the city rose up in battle to protect their leader rather than surrendering on their knees with hands in the air)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if they paint a picture of the Shchemites laying down without putting up a fight, but Rashi and numerous other commentaries point out that the brothers waited for the 3rd day post circumcision. The 3rd day, according to Rashi, is the most painful and difficult day. The brothers then attacked the city unexpectedly while they were in extreme pain. Thus the pasuk states   ויבאו על העיר בטח- they approached the city confidently. Rashi explains they were confident because the shchemites were in pain. The pasuk also goes on to say ויהרגו כל זכר- they killed every male. There is no mention of a battle (וילחמו). This seems to imply that not much of. A fight was put up and that the shchemites were rather vulnerable.

Comment: Just to add ,Maharil Diskin explains that there was no fight with the people ,however Shechem and Chamor put up a fight since they  circumcised themselves right away so they healed before Shimon and Levi came ,the diyuk is lifi Chareiv כווְאֶת־חֲמוֹר֙ וְאֶת־שְׁכֶ֣ם בְּנ֔וֹ הָֽרְג֖וּ לְפִי־חָ֑רֶב וַיִּקְח֧וּ אֶת־דִּינָ֛ה מִבֵּ֥ית שְׁכֶ֖ם וַיֵּצֵֽאוּ: